# Pandas Column based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Basically, I would like to fill in column Discount_Sub_Dpt with 'Yes' or 'No' depending on if there is a Discount for that Sub_Dpt for that week EXCLUDING the product on which that row lands (for instance I don't want any of the A rows to consider whether there is a Discount for that week for A but rather only for the products in that sub department(in most cases there is more than one other product).

I have tried using groupby with Sub_Dpt and Week to no avail.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

The Yellow column is obviously the desired outcome from the code.

[image: CSV Example]

Here is some of the code I have used, I am trying to create the column first and then update the values (but it could all potentially be wrong) (also I intentionally named the data frame df1):

```
  df1['Discount_Sub_Dpt'] = np.where((df1['Discount']=='Yes'),'Yes','No')

 grps = []                    
 grps.append(df1.Sub_Dpt.unique())
 for x in grps:
      x = str(x)
      yes_weeks = df1.loc[(df1.Discount_SubDpt == 'Yes') & (df1.Sub_Dpt_Description == x),'Week'].unique()        
  df1.loc[df1['Week'].isin(yes_weeks) & df1['Sub_Dpt_Description'] == x, 'Discount_SubDpt'] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Slightly confused...Can you explain again what the logic of the yellow column is

Comment: Of course, so the yellow column looks at all the products in the same sub_dpt excluding the product from that particular row. so for the first row it looks at Sub_Dpt Toys and looks to see if there is a discount in that sub-department for that specific week, but it excludes Product A. So for each week the column determines if there is a discount or not but excludes its own row from that determination.

Comment: Oof I see, that's interesting

Comment: Could you post the code to create that dataframe?

Comment: I am just inputting data from a csv file but this is it: df1 = pd.read_csv("1_.csv",error_bad_lines=False, header=0, dtype={"Total_Sales_y": float,"SKU_DESCRIPTION": str, "Vendor": float, "Dpt": str, "Dpt Description": str, "Sub_Dpt": str, "Sub_Dpt_Description":str, "Class":str,"Class_Description":str,"Sub_Class":str, "Sub_Class_Description":str,"SKU_Type":str,"Week":str,"Season":str,"Discount":str,"Sales_Non_AD":float,"Sales_AD":float,"Previous_Week":float})
df1 = df1[np.isfinite(df1['SKU_number'])]

Comment: If you have 3 product for Toys, and week 1, say (I, J, K) and you are looking at I then you will consider only J and K, week 1, Toys for discounts. If I'm correct till here, what happens if one of them is Yes and the Other is No?

Comment: @SahilPuri That is correct. So if one of them is Yes in Discount, than that one should become No in the Discount_Sub_Dpt column (since the other two will be No) but then the other two will be Yes for the Discount_Sub_Dpt column (for that specific week)

Comment: @RushabhMehta 
This will create the data frame (excluding the desired Discount_Sub_Dpt column):



d = {'Product': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D'], 'Week': ['1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4'],'Sub_Dpt': ['Toys','Toys','Toys','Toys','Toys','Toys','Toys','Toys','Candy','Candy','Candy','Candy','Candy','Candy','Candy','Candy'], 'Discount':['Yes','No','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','No','No','No']}




df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Comment: I literally just made it sigh

Comment: @RushabhMehta I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a `GroupBy` to map `('Week', 'Sub_Dpt')` to lists of `'Product'` only when Discount is "Yes".

Then use a list comprehension to check if any are on Discount apart from the product in question. Finally, map a Boolean series result to "Yes" / "No".

Data from @SahilPuri.

```
# GroupBy only when Discount == Yes
g = df1[df1['Discount'] == 'Yes'].groupby(['Week', 'Sub_Dpt'])['Product'].unique()

# calculate index by row
idx = df1.set_index(['Week', 'Sub_Dpt']).index

# construct list of Booleans according to criteria
L = [any(x for x in g.get(i, []) if x!=j) for i, j in zip(idx, df1['Product'])]

# map Boolean to strings
df1['Discount_SubDpt'] = pd.Series(L).map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})

print(df1)

   Product  Week Sub_Dpt Discount Discount_SubDpt
0        A     1    Toys      Yes              No
1        A     2    Toys       No             Yes
2        A     3    Toys       No              No
3        A     4    Toys      Yes             Yes
4        B     1    Toys       No             Yes
5        B     2    Toys      Yes              No
6        B     3    Toys       No              No
7        B     4    Toys      Yes             Yes
8        C     1   Candy       No              No
9        C     2   Candy       No              No
10       C     3   Candy      Yes              No
11       C     4   Candy      Yes              No
12       D     1   Candy       No              No
13       D     2   Candy       No              No
14       D     3   Candy       No             Yes
15       D     4   Candy       No             Yes
```

Comment: Thank you once again! This works very well with my csv

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the following is a bit crazy, but it works pretty nicely, so listen up.

First, we are going to build a `NetworkX` graph as follows.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
G = nx.Graph()
Prods = df.Product.unique()
G.add_nodes_from(Prods)
```

We now add edges between our nodes (which are all of the products) whenever they belong to the same sub_dpt. In this case, since A and B share a dept, and C and D, do, we add edges AB and CD. If we had ABC in the same department, we would add AB, AC, BC. Confusing, I know, but just trust me on this one.

```
G.add_edges_from([('A','B'),('C','D')])
```

Now comes the fun part. We need to convert your Discount column from Yes/No to 1/0.

```
df['Disc2']=np.nan
df.loc[df['Discount']=='Yes','Disc2']=1
df.loc[df['Discount']=='No','Disc2']=0
```

Now we pivot the data

```
tab = df.pivot(index = 'Week',columns='Product',values = 'Disc2')
```

And now, we do this

```
tab = pd.DataFrame(np.dot(tab,nx.adjacency_matrix(G,Prods).todense()), columns=Prods,index=df.Week.unique())
tab[0].astype(bool)
df = df.merge(tab.unstack().reset_index(),left_on=['Product','Week'],right_on=['level_0','level_1'])
df['Discount_Sub_Dpt']=df[0]
print(df[['Product','Week','Sub_Dpt','Discount','Discount_Sub_Dpt']])
```

You may ask, why go through this trouble? Well, two reasons. First, its far more stable. The other answers can't handle all possible cases of your problem. Second, it's much faster than the other solutions. I hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this solution. The only thing is that the example I posted is a very large oversimplification so I have 100s of products that share the same department. Thus, the second step will not apply without much manual work.

Comment: It actually isn't all that much

Comment: I can write a script if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this might not scale well, but should be easy to read.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data= [[ 'A',    1,  'Toys', 'Yes',  ],
[   'A',    2,  'Toys', 'No',   ],
[   'A',    3,  'Toys', 'No',   ],
[   'A',    4,  'Toys', 'Yes',  ],
[   'B',    1,  'Toys', 'No',   ],
[   'B',    2,  'Toys', 'Yes',  ],
[   'B',    3,  'Toys', 'No',   ],
[   'B',    4,  'Toys', 'Yes',  ],
[   'C',    1,  'Candy',    'No',   ],
[   'C',    2,  'Candy',    'No',   ],
[   'C',    3,  'Candy',    'Yes',  ],
[   'C',    4,  'Candy',    'Yes',  ],
[   'D',    1,  'Candy',    'No',   ],
[   'D',    2,  'Candy',    'No',   ],
[   'D',    3,  'Candy',    'No',   ],
[   'D',    4,  'Candy',    'No',   ],], columns=['Product', 'Week', 'Sub_Dpt',        'Discount'])
df2 = df1.set_index(['Product', 'Week', 'Sub_Dpt'])
products = df1.Product.unique()
df1['Discount_SubDpt'] = df1.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if 'Yes' in df2.loc[(list(products[products != x['Product']]), x['Week'], x['Sub_Dpt']), 'Discount'].tolist() else 'No', axis=1)
```

The first step creates a Multindex Dataframe.

Next, we get the list of all products

Next, for each row, we take out the same week and Sub Department and remove the product.

In this list if there is a discount, we select 'Yes' else 'No'

Edit 1:

If you don't want to create another dataframe (save memory, but will be a bit slower)

```
df1['Discount_SubDpt'] = df1.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if 'Yes' in df1.loc[(df1['Product'] != x['Product']) & (df1['Week'] == x['Week']) & (df1['Sub_Dpt'] == x['Sub_Dpt']), 'Discount'].tolist() else 'No', axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm not thrilled with it, but it should cover most cases.

Comment: I'm working on something that hopefully should run faster

Comment: @SahilPuri . this is not working for me, the new column is only No's

Comment: Fixed, I forgot to convert it into a list.

Comment: @SahilPuri This works! The only issue I'm having is when I try to use my csv. I get this output: KeyError: ('100', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Hmmm, not sure, are the data types in the columns consistent? are you using the `df1` method or the `df2` one ?

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but here's a go. I used the sample df in the comments above.

```
df1['dis'] = df1['Discount'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x =="Yes" else 0)
df2 = df1.groupby(['Sub_Dpt','Week']).sum()
df2.reset_index(inplace = True)
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on=['Sub_Dpt','Week'], right_on =['Sub_Dpt','Week'])
df3['Discount_Sb_Dpt'] = np.where(df3['dis_x'] < df3['dis_y'], 'Yes', 'No')
df3.sort_values(by=['Product'], inplace = True)
df3
```